# OpenNMS alert when a folder is not empty?

Tags: opennms

I'm trying to create an OpenNMS alert when a certain folder ISN'T empty but can't seem to find a way of doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a service which goes down if your folder is empty. See the [short video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B92pfiWjtrLQMjdsNGFYQ2ZCMU0/view?pref=2&pli=1). By default notifications are turned off. Every service down event will be notified by default. You can be more granular by filtering on nodes and services. The default setting will send a mail to the admin user. You set a mail address in the user of the admin. To configure the access to your mail server, configure the [javamail-configuration.properties](https://www.opennms.org/wiki/Javamail-configuration.properties). I just tried to figure out where you stuck exactly.

Comment: Not sure I uderstand how your video or answer solve my question, you just enabled snmp alerts on the host. Yes, I want to configure an email alert when a folder isn't empty, I know how to configure email alerts but I can't find a way to base it on 'folder isn't empty condition'

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to poll the certain directory for the empty condition with an agent on your host system and expose the status, e.g. [Net-SNMP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-System_Monitoring_Tools-Net-SNMP-Extending.html). You can create a service by using the [SNMP Monitor](http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/18.0.0/guide-admin/guide-admin.html#_snmpmonitor) to poll the status of the exposed OID and create a mail notification for this particular service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.  I have performed similar tasks using simple perl and bash scripts on Linux.
OpenNMS allows you to create polling configurations based on scripts.  Your script is expected to output "0" or "1", with 0 representing "OK" and 1 representing "Not OK".

You could use the GeneralPurposePoller:
https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/GeneralPurposePoller

However, it seems that you should instead use the SystemExecuteMonitor:
https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/SystemExecuteMonitor